# $y$-axis on HR diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, astrophysics, stars, luminosity

I have an exercise where I have to determine the luminosity of a star with 10 000K. However, I'm confused about how to read off the $y$-axis on the graph when the scale is uneven. What is the function of the horizontal lines and am I supposed to use them to determine the reading of the $y$-axis.

The acceptable range of the answer is 30-40 solar luminosities.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines are drawn on "log-log" graph paper. So the horizontal lines are at (e.g.) 10, 20, 30, 40, and so-on up to 100; then 200, 300, 400 etc. until you reach 1000, and then 2000, 3000...

The lines are unevenly spaced because it is a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to think as the scales of logarithmic and the take the anti-log?

[image]